# Form $4$ new symbols with the most common symbols

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Suppose we have $6$ symbols, say $A,B,C,D,E,F$. We are asked to form $4$ new symbols using the  $6$ symbols with the addition operation.

For example, the $4$ new symbols  can be $A+C+E, F+E+A, D+C+A, A+F+D$. There are some restrictions on the symbols, they are

$1)$each symbol appears only once in the $4$ new symbols

$2)$ the total number of each symbols in the $4$ new symbols must be less than $4$

I am looking for a way to make the $4$ symbols contain as many common symbols as possible. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not write all $+$ out for better visibility.

I think the way of maximizing the number of common symbols results in the following (or similar by permutation) solution

$$ABCD,ABCD+E,ABCD+F,ABCD+EF$$ which has 4 common symbols, which is maximal. You cannot have 6 commons symbols because this will yield only 1 new symbol, and you cannot have 5 common symbols because this will yield only two new symbols. ($ABCDE,ABCDE+F$).

Comment: May I know what is your intuition of getting the answer?

Comment: I noticed that you can create four different symbols just using two symbols in all 4 combinations appended to a existring 'string'. Then I tried to maximize the number of common symbols, so no huge calculations.